# Having trouble getting PHP session to "remember" post data on refresh

Tags: php, sql, session, authentication

I'm attempting to implement a simplistic user/login interface on my website.

I can 'login' just fine with a standard HTML form checking input against a database, but the username/password input is lost when I refresh the page after a successful login.

I did some research and discovered that session variables are a way to get around this. So I added a "session_start();" line at the top of each relevant page (login.php, index.php). Still, I am unable to refresh a page and stay "logged in".

Here's the code:

login.php -

```
<?php
session_start();
include "db_connect.php";
?>

<html>
<body>

<h3>Login form:</h3>

<form action='index.php' method='POST'>
  User:
  <input type="text" name="user">
  Pass:
  <input type="password" name="pass">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

index.php -

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
$_SESSION["pass"] = $_POST['pass'];

$session_user = $_SESSION['user'];
$session_pass = $_SESSION['pass'];

?>

<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>


<?php
include "../db_connect.php";


$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE (user = '$session_user' && password = '$session_pass')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        include "index_detail.php";
 }
} else {
    echo "There was an error logging in.";
}

?>
```

My code logs in and displays what I want just once, but all form post data (user/pass) is lost upon refresh. What am I doing wrong? I really want to capture this "logged in" feel.

Thanks.

Comment: You trying to set session variables by post. So when you refresh your page it doesn't get the post variables. So it initialises with blank. Therefore you don't stay logged in.

Comment: Ah, I see that now. What can I do to persist the username/password then?

Comment: There are several example for 'remember me' on internet. Check it. In your code you have to check session in login page. If it has value simply load it in input tag.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to redirect to that file ? If yes then wrong way.

```
 include "index_detail.php";
```

After fetching the data set from the DB store that into the SESSION variable and redirect to your desired page using

```
header("Location:FILE.php");
```

And in that redirect file make sure to check the SESSION variable and include that SESSION file at header too where you want that Logged in SESSION to be maintained.

For that you need to make a new session file where it will be checking continuously whether Session Exists or Destroyed.

Example"

```
<?php
require('db.php');
session_start();
$check=$_SESSION['login_username'];

$db = new db();
$con= $db->dbconnect();
$query="SELECT emailid FROM `admin_users` WHERE emailid='$check' ";
$session=$db->getrows($query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($session))
{
    $login_session=$row['emailid'];

}


 if(!isset($login_session))
{
header("Location:LOGINPAGE.php");
}

?>
```

Edited: getrows() is custom function which is created in db.php which queries the DB only and return result.

Comment: Thanks. Got the functionality I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

login.php

```
   <?php
session_start();
include "db_connect.php";
?>

<html>
<body>

<h3>Login form:</h3>

<form action='index.php' method='POST'>
  User:
  <input type="text" name="user">
  Pass:
  <input type="password" name="pass">
  <br><br>
  <input name="submit "type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
   <?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST[submit])) {
$session_user = $_POST['user'];
$session_pass = $_POST['pass'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION[user]) && isset($_SESSION[pass])) {
$session_user = $_SESSION['user'];
$session_pass = $_SESSION['pass'];
}
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>


<?php
include "../db_connect.php";


$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE (user = '$session_user' && password = '$session_pass')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     $_SESSION[user]=$session_user;
     $_SESSION[pass]=$session_pass;
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        include "index_detail.php";
 }
} else {
    echo "There was an error logging in.";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution agnostic of my actual implementation.

There are 3 files for this demonstration: form.php, save_to_session.php, and access_session_variables.php.

form.php
 - starts session, takes user input, posts form values to save_to_session.php

```
<?php session_start();?>

<html>

<body>

<form action='save_to_session.php' method='POST'>

  text-in:
  <input type="text" name="text1">
  text-in2:
  <input type="text" name="text2">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

save_to_session.php - starts session, saves posted form values to session variables, redirects to access_session_variables.php

```
<?php session_start(); 

$_SESSION['text-in'] = $_POST['text1'];
$_SESSION["text-in2"] = $_POST['text2'];
header( 'Location: access_session_variables.php' ) ; 

?>
```

access_session_variables.php - now the values are saved to the session, refreshing the page won't affect them. this file simply outputs them

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['text-in'];
echo $_SESSION['text-in2'];

?>
```

Thanks everyone. I learned a bit about how HTTP is 'stateless' and how I can create concurrent user interactions by storing unique session information for individual clients.

Comment: It is not necessary that every working code is good code. There is no need of making separate files for set session and get session. Just check session in further pages of login. If there is no session for username just redirect it to login page.